# Hashing Passwords with Vercel-Edge Adapter in Qwik City

Tags: hash, vercel, password-encryption, qwik, qwikjs

I have the following code, which uses the `argon2-browser` package to hash the user's password in a server function:

```js
export const authSignup = server$(async function (
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  email: string,
  password: string,
  passwordConf: string,
  username: string,
) {

  ...

  const name = firstName.trim() + ' ' + lastName.trim()
  const hash = await argon2.hash({ pass: password, salt: 'somesalt' })

  ...
})
```

When deploying to Vercel using the `Vercel-Edge` adapter (using `npm run deploy`), I get the following error message:

```bash
RollupError: Cannot bundle Node.js built-in "path" imported from "node_modules/argon2-browser/dist/argon2.js". Consider disabling ssr.noExternal or remove the built-in dependency.
```

Does anyone know how to get around this, or if there is another package that lets you hash passwords without this issue? Ideally this would not require moving off of Vercel. TYA!

Answer (score 1):

I switched to `bcrypt` and added this to my `vite.config.ts`:

```js
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                crypto: 'crypto-browserify',
                stream: 'stream-browserify',
                util: 'util-browser',
                events: 'events-browserify-mfsu',
            },
        },
        ssr: {
            external: ['bcrypt', 'stream', 'util', 'events'],
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting path to external?

```
vite: {
  ssr: { external: ['path'] }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I get the same error

Comment: I saw you solved the issue with a different library. Great